# Accompaniment for salty soup?

Tags: soup

I've made a soup that has a fairly salty, this is by design. The taste of the soup has turned out well. What I'm looking for is a good accompaniment or palette cleanser to counter the salt but compliment the taste. The soup is a Apple and Gammon with a vegetable stock base.

Comment: I'd go for a fresh baked crostini. Simply sliced bread soaked in olive oil and baked under a grill. If you think you need some freshness to offset the salty broth you can drizzle them with a bit of lemon juice.

Comment: I'd try to combine this with bread and tzatziki dip, to my taste the potassium in cucumbers balances the salt, allowing very salty things not to taste oversalted.

Comment: @EugenePetrov: I agree that cucumber is a good balance to salt, but do you have anything to back up the idea that it's specifically potassium that has that effect?

Comment: @Max From some reading I did after comment it's appears to be the opposite. Although cucumber as a whole will help the potassium will add a salt taste if anything. What potassium is good for is countering the effects of salt on the body e.g. High blood pressure. Regardless I went with the Crostini suggestion since it was easier and I had the ingredients already.

Comment: Right: any potassium occurring in food is not metallic potassium (which reacts violently with water) but usually as a salt, such as potassium chloride, which tastes... salty (and is used as a substitute for table salt, sodium chloride).

Comment: @Max I tell this from my experience that cucumbers, potatoes, coconut water, zuccini almost can't be oversalted, though meat and fish are easily can. I think it's combination of water and potassium... though it's just an assumption

Comment: @EugenePetrov Interesting as what you say is generally right but it shouldn't be the potassium that causes the effect so I wonder what it is.

Comment: @Max I doubt there was a research on this topic, but potassium is only 0.6 times saltiness of sodium, which is main ion responsible for the saltiness, and maybe potassium substitutes sodium in oversaturated with salt taste receptors. And anion plays its role here too, sodium bicarbonate is not so salty, sodium glutamate is rather sweet than salty, and I think the potassium in cucumber is mostly in form of some organic salt too.

Comment: and to my taste taking water as 0 and salt as 10 points of saltiness cucumber and coconut water are -5 points :) but my taste far from normal as I eat a lot of salt, I don't add salt while cooking because people complained it's way oversalted.

Comment: @EugenePetrov The substitution hypothesis is interesting, thank you.